# ruby on rails redirecting to old param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an option for a user to update their username in their profile. However, when the url for their profile has been set as `localhost/user/username` and when they submit their changes, they are redirected to their old username (not the new updated one).

Here is my update from users_controller.rb

Any suggestions?

```
 def update
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
    @page_title = "Edit Profile"
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to(user_url,
          :notice => "Your profile has been saved.") }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors,
          :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

also, I'm using

```
def to_param
      username
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't `user_url` take `@user` as an argument? How have you defined your route for that?

One thing I can think of immediately is `@user.reload!`.

Comment: I'm just using `resources :users` in `routes.rb`

Comment: Doing that might allow someone to edit another user. Change that over to `@user = current_user` (depending on which lib you're using for authentication). If you want admins to be able to edit users then I'd put a conditional in there. Something like `@user = current_user.admin ? User.find_by_username(params[:id]) : current_user`.

Comment: @michaeltomer I totally agree with you here. Only the current_user should be able to edit his / her profile. Although, regarding second point, it is very rare where you'd allow even Admins to edit users profile except for password reset or some such thing.